# BeautifulSoup Python3 version

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, traceback

I keep getting this traceback. I've used BeautifulSoup before with Python3 so I'm kind of confused as to why I would get this error now...
'''Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spider.py", line 7, in 
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "/home/cambam/Desktop/Python/Coursera/P4E/CapStone/pagerank/bs4/**init**.py", line 54
    'You are trying to run the Python 2 version of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work.'<>'You need to convert the code, either by installing it (`python setup.py install`) or by running 2to3 (`2to3 -w bs4`).'
                                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obtaining python2 code in the first place sounds inconvenient. Better to grab the right version at the outset.

Delete the old Soup code you downloaded, and grab a fresh copy:

```
$ python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

If you look at `which pip` or `pip --version` you may notice that it corresponds to python2. Using the `-m` module syntax above will ensure that you get a proper python3 version that installs libraries where python3 will look for them.

Answer (score 0):

OK I already figured out the answer.

First I ran 'sudo apt install 2to3' in the command line

Then 2to3 -w bs4

I ran the program again and now it works.